# Save records from Salesforce to Google drive in .csv format

Tags: integration, google-drive

I have a scenario where I have to save my records for five objects namely contact , account , lead , campaign and campaign members as a backup on google drive in a .csv format for each object separately.

This will be daily process , is their a way I can achieve the above mentioned from my Salesforce Org.

Comment: Yes you need to write code for this. Did you tried anything?

Comment: There is Command Line Interface (CLI) for [dataloader] (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm)  which would help you take backup of your objects in local machine. And you can schedule this job using windows scheduler to run daily or on any interval. But I am not sure about how will you upload those CSVs to google drive.

Comment: @TusharSharma yes, I'am trying to create a .csv for diffrent objects but how t save into google drive is still pending . Would it be good to create .csv in salesforce or should we do it outside salesforce since their are a large number of records present in the salesforce org which have to be processed

Comment: first you need to do auth process with drive then after that schedule a batch how will create csv and upload that to drive.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://theforcetimes.wordpress.com/tag/upload-files-from-salesforce-to-google-drive/) which provides details about uploading files from salesforce to google drive.

Comment: This previous answer addresses actually uploading the file once created. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40162/upload-file-on-google-drive?rq=1